# How to get battery warning beeping sounds back in 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, sound, battery

I recently upgrade to ubuntu 20.04.
Now I don't hear an internal beeb sound from the computer when it's about to run out of battery, which it suddenly just shuts down(first priority). I would very much like to be warned a at least a few minutes before so I get a chance to find a charger.
Its important that the warning can be heard even if I have headphones plugged and not wearing them. so I get a chance to react if I'm not at the computer.
It also used to beeb 2 times if the charge fell out or was plugged in.
how do I change this back?  much help would be appreciated.
I cant find an answer other places thank :)

Comment: What was your previous Ubuntu version/flavor where this feature was available?

Comment: I think it was 18.04